# strict mode does not appear the use of the implicit arguments?

Tags: javascript

Is this correct? Is this new?

I mean the implicit arguments that each function has btw.

I noticed that my code is failing when I use arguments in strict mode, if I remove strict mode not problem ... is this new or has it always been this way ?

```
console.log('foo.js running');
(function() {
  // 'use strict';
  // unexpected arguments in strict mode ...
```

and here is where I use it:

```
  _.extend = function(obj) {
    _.each(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), function (object) {
      _.each(object, function(val, key){
        obj[key] = val;
      })
    });
    return obj;
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind finishing off the `(function() …)` snippet? At least how it ends. As it stands, there is no technical reason why it shouldn’t work.

Comment: That code [works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/hb4ag7sg/1/) in strict mode.

Comment: There are 2 issues you will face immediately in Strict Mode:. First `this` will fail for a non-method function. Second, all undeclared variables (those without a `var` declaration before they’re used) will fail. Parameter variables are automatically declared, so they don’t need `var`. Otherwise, this code should work. We need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

No, strict mode does not prevent use of `arguments`. It does *change* it slightly: The `arguments` object is no longer tied to the named parameters, so:

```js
function loose(a) {
  console.log(a);
  arguments[0] = "bar"; // Changes `a`
  console.log(a);
}
function strict(a) {
  "use strict";
  console.log(a);
  arguments[0] = "bar"; // Does not change `a`
  console.log(a);
}
loose("foo");
strict("foo");
```